# How to estimate shape parameter of spherical radial basis function

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, radial-basis-functions

In [this paper about positive definite kernels](http://www.math.iit.edu/%7Efass/PDKernels.pdf) they introduce the extension of the radial basis function (RBF or Gaussian Kernel)

$$
K_{rbf}(x,y) = e^{-\epsilon^2||x-y||^2}
$$

for the unit sphere

$$
K_{srbf}(x,y) = e^{-2\epsilon(1- \langle x , y \rangle)}
$$

Instead of the squared euclidean distance $||x-y||^2$ it uses the cosine similarity $1-\langle x , y \rangle$.

Both use the shape parameter $\epsilon$, with $\epsilon^2 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ from the more common gaussian form. In the code used by [this paper about kernel MRCD](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.02046.pdf) they implement a RBF kernel and estimate $\sigma$ for a dataset $D$ robustly using

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\underset{x,y \in D}{median}\big(||x-y||^2\big)}
$$

Now I am testing said kernel MRCD for data on a hypersphere and wanted to extend the originally implemented RBF kernel to the sphere, but how do I then estimate $\sigma$? So far I landed on

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\underset{x,y \in D}{median}\big((1-\langle x , y \rangle)^2\big)}
$$

which simply replace the euclidean distance by the cosine similarity. But since the extension of the kernel to the sphere itself wasn't just a change of distance this doesn't feel quite right.

What other heuristics can be used? The application is for unsupervised outlier detection so something like a grid search should not be used and a direct estimate from the dataset is needed.

**Edit**:

Thanks for pointing out that if $||x||=||y||=1$ then:

$$
||x-y||^2 = ||x||^2 - 2\langle x , y \rangle + ||y||^2 = 2-2\langle x , y \rangle = 2(1-\langle x , y \rangle)
$$

so on the unit sphere cosine similarity and euclidean distance coincide. I am still wondering though why instead of $\epsilon^2$ the second one uses $\epsilon$? And also if this way of estimating $\sigma$ still holds true on the unit sphere?

Comment: $\|x-y\|^2=2(1-\langle x,y\rangle)$ if $\|x\|^2=\|y\|^2=1.$

Comment: Thank you @GérardLetac ! I completely missed that. The fact that the second kernel only uses $\epsilon$ instead of $\epsilon^2$ is then probably only stylistic right? MATLAB is giving me quite different results for $\sigma$ though which might be due to numerical issues (floating point rounding)

Comment: This type of hyperparameter is often estimated using maximum likelihood, assuming the data follows a Gaussian process given by the kernel interpreted as the process' covariance function. See Chapter 5 of [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/)